# Красные галки возле классов и проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d, visual-studio-2017

Создаю игру в unity. Пишу скрипты в Visual Studio 2017. Использую SourceTree.
Появилась проблема при запуске скрипта VS выдает "Не удалось добавить проект в решение: проект с таким именем уже существует в решении",[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя проекта с таким именем нет. При изменений кода VS ругается что проект был изменен вне среды.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] У измененного класса и проекта появляются красные галочки. Да и вообще в решений пишет, что проектов 2, а он один. Прошу помощи у кого какие идей.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Проект с таким именем у вас на скрине, а красная галка у солюшена означает что файл солюшена изменился (вы ведь git используете?) Также как красная галка у файла означает, что содержимое файла изменилось с последнего коммита.

Comment: Да я использую git. Теперь я понял, что означают красные галки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить папки `.vs, Library, Temp, obj` и все файлы в корне проекта `.csproj, .sln, .suo`. После повторного открытия проекта в `Unity` должны восстановится и папки и решения и при этом большинство странных ошибок исчезает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это не помогло избавится от сообщений о том, что  "проект с таким именем уже существует в решении"